# Segmentation fault in Cygwin and default variable initialisation

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, struct, cygwin

Why does the `if` statement cause a segmentation fault when I compile in Cygwin ? Compiling in Linux via GCC works though.

After some research, I found out that it could be due to the fact that the `struct int` variable isn't initialised to 0 by default ?

However, doesn't C initialise all global and static variables to 0 ? The `struct test` is a global struct, so why doesn't it initialise to 0 ?

```
int x;  
int count = 20;

struct test {
        int ID;
       };
       typedef struct test GG;
       GG *ptr[200];

    int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
    {
        for(x = 0; x<count; x++) {
            if(!(*ptr[x]).ID){
                printf("true\n");
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: what is count? Even if declared somewhere, it's UB if uninitialised.

Comment: Please post that code which is giving you segfault.This code does not seems to be even compilable.Like what is `int int main` and `ID_N`. I think `ID_N` should be `ID`.

Comment: Have you compiled with `-Wall`? That includes the `-Wuninitialized` warning which checks for automatic variables used without initialisation. From GCC's website: __Warn if an automatic variable is used without first being initialized or if a variable may be clobbered by a setjmp call. In C++, warn if a non-static reference or non-static ‘const’ member appears in a class without constructors.__ As Bathsheba pointed out, it could be some other variable causing you grief.

Comment: @Dayalrai : Added some more info, code shows segmentation fault now.

Comment: @Nobilis : I tried with -Wall, there are no warnings for uninitialized variables.

Comment: @iridescent I think Dayalrai has got your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GG *ptr[200];` ptr is an array of pointers to GG type of structure.You are trying to access these pointers which does not have any memory location.

You need to allocate memory to each pointer of this array like below-

```
  for(x = 0; x<200; x++)
ptr[x] = malloc(sizeof(struct test));
```